# How to do output-format dependent substitution in Sphinx

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext

Using [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org), how can I make a substitution depending on the output-format?

Basically, I would like to have something like

```
if html:
   |CLICK| unicode:: U+21E8
elif latex:
   |CLICK| raw:: latex
   
              $\LongRightArrow$
```

but I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `.. only::` directive instead. While it is normally used with flags (or tags as sphinx puts  it), the output format is made available as a tag as well:

```
.. only:: html

   .. raw:: html

      <a href="http://www.google.com">google</a>

.. only:: latex

   latex specific
```

Official documentation:
https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#including-content-based-on-tags